# compiling my simple C code

Tags: c

Whenever I try to compile the following code, I can enter the initial value I ask for but then nothing happens. Also, there is no build error that being picked up so i don't know why this is happening. Please help and thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int n;
int allDaPrimes[1000];
int counter = 0;
bool isPrime(int number);
int i;

int main()
{
    printf("Please enter a numeric value now: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 2; i <n; i++){
        isPrime(i);
        if(isPrime(i)) {
            allDaPrimes[counter] = i;
            counter++;
        }
        }


    for(i= 0; i==counter; i++){
        printf("%d", allDaPrimes[i]);
    }
    return 0;

   }

bool isPrime(int number) {
    for (i= 2; i <= number; i++){
        if(number % i == 0 && number != i){
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I suppose that's because your `isPrime` function has a terrible complexity, so it runs forever. Try limiting to `int(sqrt(number)+0.5)` you'll have the same results, much faster. note: you're calling it twice in your loop,; making it even worse.

Comment: If it runs to the point you can enter a value, it's not a *compiling* problem, because your code compiled, linked and executed. Now it's a *debugging* problem, and for that you use a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: consider using a sieve algorithm instead of that. (lookup sieve of erathostenes)

Comment: which value are you entering? Entering 1 million creates a 10**12 loop.

Comment: goodness guys thanks so much for responding so quickly! Ill look into your suggestions and update you as soon as I can.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I am just trying to enter 9 lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your variables are declared globally rather than locally in the functions where they are used. This means that you're getting conflicts between the different functions.

Take `i` for example. In the loop in `main`, you start off with it set to 2. But `isPrime()` changes it to be `n+1` because that is the last value it'll be after the loop in there finishes. But you call that twice so `i` ends up being `n+2`, so the main loop only runs once. And if you end up with any values in the array, it'll be `n+2` if `n+1` was a prime.

Comment: Good work man! In addition, was also true what stated in the other answer.

Comment: just turned all my "i" into "i, j, k ...etc" and it works!!!!! thanks so much Chris!

Comment: @PeterLouis whilst that undoubtedly "works", the correct way would be to put `int i;` at the top of the block they're used in. There's no problem with you re-using `i` in the second main loop as you're initialising it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a logic error in your code, which means your code is doing exactly what you told it to, but it's not what you had in mind in your head.

The problem is this statement

```
for(i= 0; i==counter; i++){
    printf("%d", allDaPrimes[i]);
}
```

It starts with i=0 then runs while i==counter, which is probably not what you had in mind. You probably meant: `i<counter`

Comment: Wow I am dumb! I just started learning how to code so I guess theres some serious learning pains. Thanks so much!

Comment: So i fixed that problem and made it "i<=counter" and the problem persists :(

Comment: Try inserting the number 11 as input and see if it works, if you're inputting huge numbers it may just be hanging since it's taking so long given your algorithm

Comment: Probably should have started with this but, I need the prime numbers up until (not including the number) and for them to be printed all on one line.

Also I dont get why none of the values are being stored in my array

Comment: `printf("%d", allDaPrimes[i]);` will print them all one line, but without any spaces between them...need to make that `"%d "` to make the output readable.

Comment: @ChrisTurner yea i ended up figuring that one out, unfortunately, my array isnt being populated correctly and its frustrating

Comment: In your first loop i<=n, as you seem to want to include your intput

Comment: @Simba thanks so much man for working with me here. I think I am going to try and implement a sieve algorithm to clean up some of complexity